# Run some sort of script after a mysql database is edited C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, editing

Is there a way to run some sort of script or process after a line or entry is edited in my mysql database. I'm mainly wondering because I'd like to send an email for user authentication after an entry is created. Afterwards, once the link sent to the email is clicked, I'll figure a way of updating the entry. I am most familiar with C#, but am willing to learn php for this as I'd like to anyways. Any code samples or tutorials would be awesome.

I've searched online but haven't found anything useful. Maybe I just don't know what to look for.

I don't know if this is related, but under attributes, there is an option for "on update CURRENT TIME STAMP". Would this be related?

Additional information. I use C# for client based operations and Cpanel w/ phpMyAdmin for database editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in **triggers**. Read on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

**EDIT** Your next question possibly would be: How to send email from a trigger?

Unfortunately there is not a single, trivial way to do so. These are two different approaches:

- You can write a so called [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) (or find an existing one), that would send an email and this function would be called from the trigger.
- The trigger would write the emails to be sent into a queue. (The queue might be a table or even a file). There would be a system job that would periodically read from the queue and send the emails.

Comment: I've read some examples from looking up triggers and functions and have found that a lot of people use tables to store a list of emails that have to be sent out. Afterwards, they would have a server side app look through the table and send out the tables accordingly.  

I thought about using a java app to do exactly this before hand, but thought it would be strenuous for when the app sorts through all the entries.